# On button clicked in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I developed a small Child game in `COCOs2d`.

I used an image as a button in `MenuItem`. My problem is that when I click on the Menu Button I want to allow the image to look like selected image.

The code I used is as below :

```
CCMenuItem * blueCar = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"leftblueCar.png" selectedImage:@"blue-car.png" target:self selector:@selector(onSelectCar:)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Layer on click Event and The Set image on it or do any thing What you want on new layer....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you mean how to set a different image for a button when it is selected, but if this is the case you can use something like:

```
CCMenuItemImage *aButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"button_normal.png" selectedImage:@"button_selected.png" block:^(id sender){
  // Do something when user taps button
        }];
```

If you don't want to use [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html), you can use:

```
CCMenuItemImage *aButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"button_normal.png" selectedImage:@"button_selected.png" target:self selector:@selector(aButtonTapped:)];
```